# Add 10 seconds when 5 answers are correct

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to add 10 seconds:

```
private fun countdowntimer() {
    object : CountDownTimer((time), 1000) {

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            if ((correct_answers % 5).equals(0) && correct_answers !=0 ) {
//             i want to add 10 seconds to countdown timer object also
                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + (millisUntilFinished+10000 )/ 1000)

            } else {
                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done")
            //opengameover()

        }
    }.start()

}
```

Comment: could you please argument on what the problem is? I guess you want to update the countdown timer as well, while right now you're only updated the label in the UI?

Comment: yes i want to change the countdown timer as well

Comment: You have got to cancel the current countdown and start a new one with the desired time

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try to multiply with 10 with your calculation like this

`(millisUntilFinished+10000 )*10/ 1000`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).